# How to save content to my computer from Jframe in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have some problem, can somebody help me, I am new at java. I whant to save content from jframe on my computer, and I need option to again open in program after I save that on my computer, not txt file, not pdf? Can somebody help me?
This is the jframe [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYFuD.png)

And this is code for now but it doesn't work

```
 package servis1;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

/**
 *
 * @author Boris
 */
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
     private String data;
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();

/**
 * Creates new form NewJFrame
 */
public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
}
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    Imeiprezime = new java.awt.Label();
    textField1 = new java.awt.TextField();
    label2 = new java.awt.Label();
    textField2 = new java.awt.TextField();
    label3 = new java.awt.Label();
    label4 = new java.awt.Label();
    textField4 = new java.awt.TextField();
    label5 = new java.awt.Label();
    textField5 = new java.awt.TextField();
    label6 = new java.awt.Label();
    label7 = new java.awt.Label();
    jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jComboBox2 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTextArea2 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("POTVDA O PRIJEMU NA SERVIS");

    Imeiprezime.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
    Imeiprezime.setText("Ime i prezime:");

    label2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
    label2.setText("Broj telefona:");

    label3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
    label3.setText("Proizvodjac:");

    label4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
    label4.setText("Model:");

    label5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
    label5.setText("IMEI:");

    label6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
    label6.setText("Opis kvara:");

    label7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
    label7.setText("Napomena:");

    jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Apple", "Samsung", "HTC", "Huawei" }));

    jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
    jLabel2.setText("Primio na servis:");

    jComboBox2.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Marko Markovic", "Petar Petrovic", "Janko Jankovic" }));

    jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
    jTextArea1.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

    jTextArea2.setColumns(20);
    jTextArea2.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTextArea2);

    jButton1.setText("Sacuvaj");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(23, 23, 23)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(Imeiprezime, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(label2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(label3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(label4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(label5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(label6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(label7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jComboBox1, 0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(textField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(textField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(textField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(textField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jComboBox2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 166, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton1)
                        .addGap(49, 49, 49))
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane2)))
            .addContainerGap(79, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(30, 30, 30)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addGap(25, 25, 25)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(Imeiprezime, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(textField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(24, 24, 24)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(label2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(textField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(label3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(label4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(textField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(label5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(textField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(label6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(22, 22, 22)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(label7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 41, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addComponent(jComboBox2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton1))
            .addGap(60, 60, 60))
    );

    pack();
}        


private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
           int retValue = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
        if(retValue == chooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(data));//data is string to save
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));
            String str;
            while((str = reader.readLine())!= null){
                writer.write(str + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Error!");
                    }
        }


    }                   



/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private java.awt.Label Imeiprezime;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox1;
private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea2;
private java.awt.Label label2;
private java.awt.Label label3;
private java.awt.Label label4;
private java.awt.Label label5;
private java.awt.Label label6;
private java.awt.Label label7;
private java.awt.TextField textField1;
private java.awt.TextField textField2;
private java.awt.TextField textField4;
private java.awt.TextField textField5;
// End of variables declaration
```

`

Comment: It sounds like you are asking how to save info to the computer without saving info to the computer

Comment: This program is for mobile shop, its about customers and info about fixes on    mobiles. Maybe you didnt understand me, I want to save on computer I need that, but not in txt, pdf... because when I click on that saved file I want to open in program again so I can edit that, not to open word, pdf...

Comment: So make up your own extension

Answer (score 0):

I think is not possible not storing info on the computer for retrieving before close it. I mean: when you close a program, all data is destroyed getting its RAM blocks free. So you must use something like XML file builder where you can dump the info, store it temporally on the computer (in the program folder F. E.), and then retrieve it and deleting the file.